# Fans on 100% after Bumblebee Install on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, nvidia, acpi, bumblebee, fan

Fresh install of F25. Updated everything. I installed bumblebee following the instructions here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee . Closed source managed drivers w/ multilib support. Optirun works. But as soon as I log in, the fans kick in 100% and never shut off. I tried the work around here: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthr... but it didn't turn off the fans. This is on a asus zenbook pro ux501vw

Comment: I have also tried adding acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009" to boot options

Comment: secure boot is disabled. Also tried dracut --force --regenerate-all.